# Flash Animation to Iphone

Tags: iphone, flash, animation

My designer has made a few animations for a flash game and I want to put them in my Iphone game. Is there any way to do that?

I thought of exporting all the pngs as frames. And then looping them in UIIMageview. Is there any better method to do this.

Comment: You can export it as movie (.mov) and then use it in the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing what Walter above has suggested.

Exporting the frames as pngs and then making them loop is probably your best bet then. – Walter Dec 24 '10 at 22:34

Answer (score 0):

Not really. In the future you might be able to export Flash to iPhone binaries, but I think that project got put on hold when Apple changed the AppStore guidelines. Even then I don't think it would allow it to be emmended in another App.

Comment: I just want to export the flash animation of a flying bird to the iphone game that I am creating.

Comment: Exporting the frames as pngs and then making them loop is probably your best bet then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of Hirameki? It is a flash animation only parser that lets you drop SWF animations directly into Xcode projects for iPhone. A demonstration and beta sign up is here http://www.flash-on-iphone.com